# In Apache why does 502 request do not get registed in in access logs

Tags: apache-2.4

My apache with php throws 502 intermitantly. while other response codes do get registered in apache access logs but, 502 requests do not get registered. Why this behaviour?
Does this mean that ec2 instance is closing off the connection before it reaches apache

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Apache HTTPD has an error log configured. Most of the errors thrown should be showing up in there. I'd bet your 502s are in there...

Should be in the same directory as the access log, but named error_log.